# What if I flash the ARM processor with some random firmware

Tags: c, arm, firmware, bootloader

As Pi users, we know that our boards are driven by an ARM processor. We can find these processors in tons of devices such as routers, modems, cellphones etc. An ARM developer will use C language and will probably use it's own firmware and/or some free or proprietary RTOS or run install some Linux OS similar to what happen with the Raspberry PI.

It's also known that PI boards have it's own closed proprietary firmware and bootloader. My question would be, is it possible to flash that processor using JLINK or any other Cortex Programmer device, so we can use the hardware different as intended and if so, can I roll back to it's original Raspberry Pi firmware?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi firmware is NOT ARM code. It is VideoCore code. So you must first find VideoCore assemblers and compilers .... Hint: use google

Answer (score 4):

No, that won't be possible. As such, ARM CPUs inside the Raspberry pi SoC are *slaves* to the videocore. They cannot even go out of reset until the videocore executes the right firmware which allows them to start.

Broadcom may have proprietary debugger tools which interface the videocore and start ARM CPUs at will. Even if they exist, such tools are unlikely to be made public.

Comment: "Broadcom" and "unlikely to be made public" - That's pretty much redundant. :-)